# Which Kubernetes names can begin with a number?

Tags: kubernetes, naming, aws-application-load-balancer

The [Kubernetes docs state that](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/names/) four "*commonly used name constraints*" are RFC1123 subdomain names, RFC1123 label names, RFC1035 label names, and (posix?) path segments. These constraints differ e.g. in maximum length, whether any uppercase is permissible, what symbols are permissible, and whether the first character must be a letter or can also be a numeral, etc. Which constraints apply to which Kubernetes resource kinds? As a particular example, can the name of an ingress begin with a numeral?

The motivation for this question is that the AWS Load Balancer is clunky to configure with numerical explicit rule ordering (because `alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/group.order` must be maintained to be unique among all ingresses in the group, and reassigning precedence values [requires a seperate removal stage](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticloadbalancingv2-listenerrule.html#cfn-elasticloadbalancingv2-listenerrule-priority) that seems incongruous with "infrastructure as code"), but the "implicit" default ordering is [supposed to](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.2/guide/ingress/annotations/#group.order) be alphabetic by ingress name. This suggests (for routing multiple ingresses from the same host domain) a simpler solution of just prepending a number to the name of the ingress for the more-specific path.

Comment: Maybe I not clear understand your question, but from the description of [the Ingress resource](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#the-ingress-resource): The name of an Ingress object must be a valid [DNS subdomain name](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/names/#dns-subdomain-names). This means that the name must start with an alphanumeric character and end with an alphanumeric character.  For example `2test-ingress` in your case.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewSkorkin, I was expecting to find it in the [API reference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.22/) but to no avail.

Comment: So, did this answer on your question?